# How do you create a UWP app bundle?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10, publishing

For example, the built in mail app is actually listed in the store as Mail and Calendar. Calendar shares the same listing too.

How can I publish my apps to the Microsoft Store in the same way? (Multiple apps installed through one store listing)

Comment: Because the same solution install two app package or projects and editing app manifest but need to check store allow or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Colin It seems that unless you are Microsoft Corp, you would be unable to publish multiple apps under a single listing. I have dug deep into the crevice of the C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\'all folders in this directory' and by all accounts, Mail and Calendar are two separate files.

Looking through Windows Dev Center: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/]
it may be possible to create separate file packages though and submit them during the application process under one listing. This is generally done for optional DLC content or if an app is too large and you need to split it up. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/optional-packages]. Though, without any apps to launch I am unable to verify.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Technically it is possible but it is needed to check store allows it or not